# Error trying to make symlink to subl - can't find directory

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to create a symlink to subl, but I am having issues.  The instructions read: "Assuming you've placed Sublime Text in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path, you can run:"

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Initially, I got `/Users/User/bin/subl: No such file or directory.`

So I tried making the directory with `mkdir /usr/local/bin` and running a modified version of the above command:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

That worked, but when I ran `subl --help` this error popped up:

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

I also tried `mkdir ~/bin`. No luck. I'm also concerned because the instructions say Sublime should be in the applications folder, which it is in Finder, but not under tbecks/Applications.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you do all that as the root user?

Answer (score 0):

> when I ran "subl --help" this error popped up: "-bash: subl: command
>   not found"

Most likely `/usr/local/bin` is not in your path.

Add

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

at the end of your bash configuration file( most likely /etc/bash.bashrc) and then execute the command again or confirm the command is reachable using:

```
which subl
```

**Edit:**

Even better modify the PATH in `~/.bashrc` if you wish to restrict `subl` only for you.

Comment: First off, `/etc/.bashrc` doesn't exist - it's only a dotfile in users' home directories. Secondly, you should ***never*** edit *anything* in `/etc` unless absolutely necessary, and only if you know *exactly* what you're doing. Recommending this is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @MattDMo : I meant `bash.bashrc`. I agree editing this is a bad idea. Added  a note on this.

Comment: Looks better. However, on OS X, it's just `bashrc`, not `bash.bashrc`, at least on versions up to 10.10. I'm not sure about 10.11, though.

Comment: @MattDMo : In Redhat and its clones, its again `bashrc` atleast upto Redhat 6.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I figured I'd make the comment since the OP is using OS X (you can tell from the path names being used - `/Applications`, `Sublime Text.app`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The first `ln` command you ran used `/Applications/Sublime Text.app`, but the second used `Sublime Text 2.app`. Since you tagged the question [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3), I'm assuming that's the version you're using. Here's what you need to do to get the symlink working. First, verify `subl` is in the correct spot:

```
ls -l /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

If you installed Sublime in the correct spot, something like this will print:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mattdmo  admin  158192 May 11 21:47 /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Now that we know where the original `subl` is, we can fix the mistake you made using the ST2 path:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/subl
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Next, we'll see if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` variable:

```sh
# reload bash's hashmap of executables
hash -r
# find subl, hopefully
which subl
```

If `/usr/local/bin` *is* in your `PATH`, the `which` command will print

```sh
/usr/local/bin/subl
```

If it does, you're good to go. If it doesn't, we'll need to add it to your path. Unlike another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604398/1426065) says, you should ***never*** mess around with *anything* in `/etc` unless you know exactly what you're doing. Instead, we'll make the change in your personal bash startup file. Depending on which version of OS X you're on, this file could vary. Go to your home directory by typing

```sh
cd
```

then run

```sh
ls -al
```

to show all of the files and directories, even the "hidden" ones that start with a dot/full stop `.`. You are looking for `.bashrc` or `.profile`. If both exist, or if neither exist, use `.profile`. Run

```sh
/usr/local/bin/subl ~/.profile
# or .bashrc
```

and add the following line at the bottom:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Save the file and close it. Now, you can restart Terminal and your `subl` command should be ready to use! If for some reason it still doesn't work, try adding the above line to the other file (i.e., if you just added it to `.profile`, try adding it to `.bashrc` and vice versa).

Comment: It works! Thank you! I only had to run the first part of your answer (up to which subl) to fix it.  Now I can run subl --help and it shows what I expected